# run index.html on npm

Tags: npm, npm-start

I am complete beginner so I apologize in advance.

I have installed npm with these scripts in terminal

```
1.curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
2.nvm install node
```

then I set it to run like this

```
http-server -a localhost
Starting up http-server, serving ./public
Available on:
http://localhost:8081
```

an I have an index. html in my documents that I would like to display. I have tried to just state the whole path in the browser  so like `http://localhost:8081/Documents/testServer/index.html`

But that doesn't work

Comment: You must install your tools inside the folder that contain index.html

Comment: so must first enter the folder and run 1.curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
2.nvm install node ? and do this in every folder?

Comment: Right! .. Go to the folder that contain index.html then install the tools you want then open the link .. Just test it ..

Comment: ok, thank you for help

Comment: Did it worked? ..

Comment: yes, so every time I switch off the process I have to run this ?

Comment: Sure .. Beacause this is live Server for that you must run server first to run the project .. I will post the solution as answer and you accept to help new people in Stack Overflow .. Okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the tools inside the folder that contains index.html file as below

- First  : Open the folder that contain index.html
- Second : Install Tools

  1.curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash

  2.nvm install node
- Third : Open the live server at :

  http://localhost:8081/Documents/testServer/index.html